# How to calculate that to what maximum number of times for loop can run in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, memory-management, loops, for-loop, cpu-usage

In Javascript, if we have the following code:

```
var j = 0;

for(i=0; i<j; i++){
  //JS Code
}
```

In this code, on what factors the maximum value of variable j **(that is the value upto which browser will not hang)** will depend upon (like may be Machine's RAM or Processor or may be the code being executed in the loop)?

And can this maximum permissible value calculated?

This is required as there is a large array which needs to be processed.

Thanks for any suggestions in advance.

Comment: If you have so many elements that you're afraid the browser may hang, then you might need to rethink your design. Just out of curiosity, how many elements are working with?

Comment: Please add a comment if voting down. That would help improve the things.

Comment: Thanks for the post John. Actually this data is dynamic and the number of records can increase. Thus, was wondering if its possible to know the upper limit or may be on what factors this value will depend upon.

Comment: If you're dealing with a large amount of data, you should have a look at the webworker API. This isn't supported in all browsers, but for those that do you might be able to offload the work so the client doesn't suffer too much - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_web_workers

Comment: You really want to keep from getting anywhere *close* to the limit, as long before the limit is reached your site's user is already wondering what on earth is wrong. Of course, as you failed to adequately describe the scenario in general terms, it's impossible to offer any concrete advice.

Comment: I'm not seeing any reason for downvoting this question.

Comment: It lacks detail.  Exactly what's in this "large array"?  What is it that needs to be done with the contents? Why?  Why does the processing need to happen at the client? Under what circumstances is the processing required? Etc.

Comment: @Pointy, thanks for mentioning what should have been there. But, I precisely mentioned that I wanted to request for the factors on which loop counter will depend (also quoted few which I guessed could be possible). I have not requested any solution for my array problem. Of course, in such issues, design change is the final thing we do, but that is an option used and it can not permit ignoring of the thing raised in this question, as this addresses a wider scope. Hope this adds.

Comment: @JohnP: WebWorker API looks good. Will surely give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: @NetEmp well inside that "for" loop there might be 1 line of code, or 10,000.  Don't you think that's going to have a tremendous impact on the amount of computing resources required?

Comment: @Pointy: Absolutely Pointy, that is definitely a factor and I too mentioned that in my question. And this is what I raised this question for - what all such factors are there? And how do they interrelate?

Comment: Can you describe any computing environment anywhere that provides a way to get an answer to a question like that?  It seems almost nonsensical to me.  That's why seeing actual details of your specific problem would be helpful - this question is so completely open-ended and strange that I suspect knowing more about your *real* problem would enable somebody to provide useful advice and direction.

Comment: @Pointy: The load a script takes on server can definitely be calculated. But JS runs on client's machine and hence, things are different for it. Every question has more realms to it and instead of discarding somethings as nonsensical, constructive feedback can definitely help to improve things always. Anyways, thanks for all the time. I guess may be we are not on same page of book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't calculate this, it varies too much from browser to browser. Some browsers do it by time (e.g., your code has run for more than X seconds without yielding back to the browser; on Firefox 7 the default is 10 seconds but [the user can change it](http://lifehacker.com/162574/put-off-firefox-15s-unresponsive-script-dialogue)), other browsers do it by number of operations ([IE, for instance](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/175500)).

Your best bet is to refactor your code so you avoid even beginning to approach the limit. If you have a large piece of work to do, break it into chunks, then run the chunks one after another using `setTimeout` with a timeout value of `0`. This yields back to the browser (for more than `0` milliseconds; exactly how long will vary by browser and by what other things are going on on the page).

Here's an example of counting to 10,000,000 in 100,000 iteration chunks:

```
function toAMillion() {
  var counter = 0,
      limit = 10000000,
      chunk = 100000;

  doAChunk();

  function doAChunk() {
    var target = Math.min(limit, counter + chunk);

    while (counter < target) {
      ++counter;
    }

    if (counter < limit) {
      // Schedule next chunk
      setTimeout(doAChunk, 0);
    }
    else {
      // Done
      display("Done, counter = " + counter);
    }
  }
}
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/abomet)

Comment: Thanks for sharing. But as mentioned by you - "Your best bet is to refactor your code so you avoid even beginning to approach the limit." - so how to know this 'Limit'? By performing tests? If yes, then on different browsers or also on different OS with various configurations?

Comment: @NetEmp: Let's put it this way: If you have a chunk of JavaScript that's taking more than a second or two on IE, you'll want to refactor it. Now, that's not a perfect rule, because it's actually possible to cause this slow script error on IE in less than a couple of seconds, but it's a good rule of thumb. And yes, you always need to test your code on your (main) target browsers, not least because they vary in so many ways.

Comment: Thanks for the code TJ, definitely adds alot. Will put it to use and test.

Answer (score 1):

A common practice to keep the UI responsive while processing large amounts of data is called chunking.  You carve off groups of items and use setInterval or setTimeout to wrap up the looping over each group.